# me apareció el error SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8

Estaba solucionando un problema simple que vi en una pizarra de mi escuela y no me aparecía ningún error al menos al momento de hacer el código pero a la hora de ejecutar me apareció el error SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte

Aquí el código:

```
nota =input("¿cual fue tu nota?")

if nota >4.0 <8.0: print ("felicitaciones aprobaste, vamos a comer algo")
else: print ("reprobaste que mal... bueno vamos a comer algo")

if nota >8.0: print ("estas seguro?")
```

Todo esto en python 3.9

Comment: Estas ejecutando python en alguna shell en particular?

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Tu código tiene algunos errores y por eso no funciona

El primero es, `input()` siempre devuelve un `string` por lo que al comparar la variable `nota` (Que contiene un `string`) con el `float` 4.0 y 8.0 te manda error. Esto se corrige convirtiendo el valor de `string` a `float`:

```
nota = float(input("¿Cuál fue tu nota?"))
```

Segundo, cuando haces una comparación para determinar si una variable está entre 2 valores el formato correcto es `valor_menor < variable < valor_mayor`, por lo que tu primer `if` está mal. Para corregirlo debes cambiar la línea utilizando la sintaxis correcta:

```
if 4.0 < nota < 8.0:
```

Tercero, el `if` donde comparas si la calificación es mayor a 8 debería ir relacionado con las otras condiciones, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma (**Nota**, modifiqué la comparación para que también evalúe si la calificación es 8.0, de otra forma evalúa como si hubiera reprobado)

```
if nota >= 8.0: print("¿Estas seguro?")
elif 4.0 < nota < 8.0: print ("Felicitaciones aprobaste, vamos a comer algo")
else: print ("Reprobaste que mal... bueno, vamos a comer algo")
```

Ejemplo completo aplicando los comentarios anteriores:

```
nota = float(input("¿Cuál fue tu nota?"))
print(nota)

if nota >= 8.0: print("¿Estas seguro?")
elif 4.0 < nota < 8.0: print ("Felicitaciones aprobaste, vamos a comer algo")
else: print ("Reprobaste que mal... bueno, vamos a comer algo")
```

**Nota adicional:** En tu pregunta no aclaras cuál es el valor máximo y mínimo, en este caso si escribes la calificación 152648.15 lo tomará como aprobada, de igual si ingresas números negativos lo tomará como reprobado

**Nota adicional 2:** En tu pregunta no aclaras lo que debe hacer el programa en caso de que el usuario ingrese un valor incorrecto, por ejemplo el caracter `a`, en ese caso el programa te devolverá el error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme a mejorar el código aún estoy aprendiendo y soy bastante principiante aunque aún me sigue dando el mismo problema de SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: ¿En el código que puse? ¿Cómo estás ingresando los datos?